# Apply filter if condition

Tags: java

I want to apply/or not filter for users if condition is satisfied (condition: if principal.isAdministrator() ) for this code sequence.

```
for (User oneUser : subcontractorUserRole.getUsers()
    .filter(new OTMFilter(Identity.CompanyEmployeeRel.class, selectedCounty.getSubcontractor()))
    .filter(Identity.DELETED, false))
    users.add(new GenericItem(oneUser.getId(), oneUser.getName()));
```

I want to do something like this:

```
if ( principal.isAdministrator() {
    for ( User oneUser : subcontractorUserRole.getUsers()
        //.filter(new OTMFilter(Identity.CompanyEmployeeRel.class, selectedCounty.getSubcontractor()))
        .filter(Identity.DELETED, false))
        users.add(new GenericItem(oneUser.getId(), oneUser.getName()));
} else {
    for ( User oneUser : subcontractorUserRole.getUsers()
        .filter(new OTMFilter(Identity.CompanyEmployeeRel.class, selectedCounty.getSubcontractor()))
        .filter(Identity.DELETED, false))
        users.add(new GenericItem(oneUser.getId(), oneUser.getName()));
}
```

Do you know an elegant way to write this without duplicate the loop? I can use else java 8 ...

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the Strategy pattern. In this case I'd make a function for getting `oneUser` that takes a bool (isAdmin) and sets the filters accordingly. Given that there is no other sideeffect of whether the pricipal is an admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
subcontractorUserRole.getUsers()
    .stream()
    .filter(i -> principal.isAdministrador() || new OTMFilter(Identity.CompanyEmployeeRel.class, selectedCounty.getSubcontractor()))
    .filter(Identity.DELETED, false)
    .forEach(oneUser -> users.add(new GenericItem(oneUser.getId(), oneUser.getName())));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you operate a complex logic it is better to have streaming based on predicates.

```
Predicate<User> isAdmin = u -> principal.isAdministrator();
Predicate<User> isOTMFpositive = new OTMFilter(Identity.CompanyEmployeeRel.class, selectedCounty.getSubcontractor());
Predicate<User> notDeleted = ...
Predicate<User> fullPredicate = isAdmin.or(isOTMFpositive).and(notDeleted);

subcontractorUserRole.getUsers()
    .stream()
    .filter(fullPredicate)
    .map(u -> new GenericItem(u.getId(), u.getName()))
    .collect(collect(Collectors.toList()));
```